# Dwm patches not working

Tags: 13.10

im trying to install this dwm [patch](https://github.com/joshdmiller/dwm-customizations/blob/master/03-dwm-6.0-uselessgaps.diff) but i keep getting this error ps im running a vanilla dwm-6.0 with only minor edits to config.h to change the tags

```
    can't find file to patch at input line 3
    Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
    The text leading up to this was:
    --------------------------
    |--- dwm.c.orig 2012-05-08 22:32:33.883110400 +0200
    |+++ b/dwm-6.0/dwm.c    2012-05-08 22:35:59.353105670 +0200
    --------------------------
    File to patch: dwm.c
    patching file dwm.c
    Hunk #2 succeeded at 284 (offset -12 lines).
    Hunk #3 succeeded at 479 (offset -12 lines).
    Hunk #4 succeeded at 1353 (offset -55 lines).
    Hunk #5 succeeded at 1721 with fuzz 2 (offset -68 lines).
    Hunk #6 FAILED at 2240.
    1 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file dwm.c.rej
```

so 
I'm not sure whats up with it.

Comment: What command are you using to patch it?

Comment: @Mobo sudo patch -p1 < uselessgaps.diff

Comment: Just tried patching it like you did, and I got a simmilar error. Not really sure, sorry, I don't normally use uselessgaps.

Comment: @Mobo it's okay you wouldn't how to get a similar effect with out that patch would you? like almost like a clear border between windows in tile mode

Comment: You could always use a compositor like compton and make window borders really large and 100% transparent, simulating gaps. Or manually tile it.

Comment: @mobo and that would work with DWM? the compton thing

Answer (score 1):

You've likely already resolved the problem (either by figuring this out yourself, or ignoring it), but the problem you were seeing is that the patch you're linking to expects the bstack layout to already be patched into dwm. This is pretty bad form as the bstack / bstackhoriz patch doesn't directly modify dwm.c by default (it puts it's two layouts in their own file), so patch was written by someone who took the initiative to put bstack and bstackhoriz into dwm.c. This means that the patch will **NEVER** apply against a clean dwm build.

Long story short - you can completely ignore that offset's error. You can just run `make` and will have uselessgaps in your tiled layout.

(A word of warning as well: That patch assumes `topbar` to be `True` in `config.h`. If you have `topbar` set to `False`, you'll see strange problems wherein the uselessgaps are exactly right on all but the bottom of the window. You can fix this by modifying `resizeclient` in `dwm.c` to look like this:

```
void                                                                               
resizeclient(Client *c, int x, int y, int w, int h) {                              
    XWindowChanges wc;                                                             
    gap = c->isfloating ? 0 : c->mon->lt[c->mon->sellt]->addgaps ? gappx : 0;   
    c->oldx = c->x; c->x = wc.x = x + gap;                                         
    c->oldy = c->y; c->y = wc.y = y + gap;                                         
    c->oldw = c->w; c->w = wc.width = w - (gap ? (x + w + (c->bw * 2) == c->mon->mx + c->mon->mw ? 2 : 1) * gap : 0);                                                 
    if(topbar) {                                                                
        c->oldh = c->h; c->h = wc.height = h - (gap ? (y + h + (c->bw * 2) == c->mon->my + c->mon->mh ? 2 : 1) * gap : 0); 
    } else {                                                                       
        c->oldh = c->h; c->h = wc.height = h - (gap ? (y + h + bh + (c->bw * 2) == c->mon->my + c->mon->mh ? 2 : 1) * gap : 0); 
    }

    wc.border_width = c->bw;
    XConfigureWindow(dpy, c->win, CWX|CWY|CWWidth|CWHeight|CWBorderWidth, &wc);
    configure(c);
    XSync(dpy, False);
}
```